# Where is "community wiki"?

Tags: discussion

Maybe this is a dumb question, but it's not immediately obvious to me. Here or on any SOFU site. Where is the community wiki? I see people mention it and there's even a little check box to put something as community wiki, but where is it? I don't see any obvious links and none of the FAQs seem to point this out. Is it hidden in plain sight? Is community wiki a name for some other thing but it's just called that for some historical reason?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better explained over at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

In short, community wikis are discouraged because they encourage "subjective" and "open-ended" questions.  But sometimes they do make sense.  For example, [we have a CW on rooting phones.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) I believe they removed the option for users to make their own posts into a CW.  Instead, only moderators can make a post CW. 9 times out of 10, a question that "should be CW" probably should be closed due to being subjective or not a real question.

Comment: OK, so I understand this... certain posts or types of posts get turned into CWs if they have enough content (e.g. the rooting phones you mention). So where is the link to find these posts? Is it just the tag and they're really nothing more than a regular question with a tag that everyone has agreed to respect as special?

Comment: @Eric the key difference between a normal question a CW question is that you do not gain any rep from a CW question or answer. This meta answer tells how to search for CW questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-community-wiki-questions

Comment: That helps a lot. The short answer is, I can put 'wiki:1' in the search box or there's an URL I can use. Seems a strange way to operate, but at least I know now. Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can still make *answers* community wiki, in such cases where you want to invite other users to create a collaborative answer.

But for questions, it was causing a lot of problems, so the option was removed.